# How can the residuals and the fits of a regression model be correlated?

Tags: regression, least-squares, residuals, linear-algebra

In the context of statistical regression and OLS, I understand that $Y$ lives in a n-dimensional space and has variance $\sigma^2$.
The Hat Matrix, $H$, corresponds to an orthogonal projection of a given observation of $Y$ onto the column space of $X$, providing an estimate of $Y$, called $\hat{Y}$. Similarly, $(I-H)$ corresponds to an orthogonal projection of $Y$ onto a hyperplane perpendicular to the column space of $X$.

Now, if $Y$ (and, by consequence, the error terms) are uncorrelated, how can its orthogonal projection onto two different planes become correlated? A geometric intuition would be helpful.

Comment: What makes you think that the residuals and fits are correlated?

Comment: I think the wording on the title might be misleading. My question is not how can residuals be correlated with the fits, but, rather, how can either residuals OR fits be correlated with itself (in the sense of potentially having non-zero covariance terms).

Comment: This can be seen from the fact that Var(Y^)=(sigma^2)H and Var(e)=(sigma^2)(I-H)

Comment: Sample residuals are correlated with each other because they all depend on the same coefficient estimates. If you have a reasonable sample size and a good model the residual correlation should be weak.